# Decoding DoMenuItem (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to decode what the following are doing:

```
DoCmd.DoMenuItem 0, 1, 0, , A_MENU_VER20
DoCmd.DoMenuItem 0, 1, 1, , A_MENU_VER20
```

The help file doesn't tell me much except that it's commands from MS Access 2.0.

I think part of it is undoing an operation (based only on context) but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the immediate window:

```
?A_FILE
 0
?A_EDITMENU
 1
?A_UNDO
 0
?A_UNDOFIELD 
 1
```

Based on: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128425

So you have:

```
Undo Typing          CTRL+Z
      DoCmd DoMenuItem A_FORMBAR, A_EDITMENU, A_UNDO,, A_MENU_VER20

Undo Current Field / Undo Current Record  ESC
      DoCmd DoMenuItem A_FORMBAR, A_EDITMENU, A_UNDOFIELD,, A_MENU_VER20
```

Comment: Thank you!!! If I could find the developer who chose to do things like this in the app I inherited (and this is not the worst of it), I'd have to resist the urge sterilise them with a dull & rusty knife.

Comment: As to those developers we'd like to murder, I often find code like that in the projects I'm working on, and it turns out the developer's name in most cases is "David W. Fenton."

Comment: "What crack-addicted chimp wrote this mess!!!!  Oops ... um ... me."  But I won't tell you how many times I've said that.  :-)